# Why always says syntax error in my code?

Tags: shell

In this shell code, I have no idea why always say I have a syntax error and I use this function to calculate the medium and average of row number.

```
rows()
{ echo -e "Average:\tMedian:";
while read line
do
    array=($line)
    lineavg=0;
    linemed=0;
    medpos=0;



    for((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++))
    do
        let "lineavg+=${array[$i]}"
    done

    cols＝${#array[@]}

    let "lineavg=$lineavg+($cols/2)"

    let "$lineavg/=$cols"
    let "medpos=($cols/2)"  
    sorted=($(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"| sort -g))

    if [ $((cols%2)) -eq 0 ]; then
        let "medpos--"
        if [[ "array[$medpos]"<"array[medpos+1]" ]]; then
            let "medpos++"
        fi
    fi
    let "linemed=${sorted[$medpos]}"

    echo -e $lineavg '\t\t' $linemed
done<$inputfile
}
```

Comment: ***Where*** does it say you have a syntax error? Try creating a [mcve].

Comment: it says in between the line "cols=${#array[@]}" and let "medpos=($cols/2)"

Comment: Show the **exact** error output from running this function. Is this `bash` or `/bin/sh` or some other shell?

Comment: exact error like this:Average: Median:
test1.sh: line 27: cols＝0: command not found
test1.sh: line 29: let: lineavg=0+(/2): syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/2)")
test1.sh: line 30: let: 0/=: attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "/=")
test1.sh: line 31: let: medpos=(/2): syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/2)")
test1.sh: line 39: let: linemed=: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")

Comment: Possible DOS line endings in part of the script?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
let "$lineavg/=$cols"
```

To:

```
let "lineavg/=$cols"
```